# Bug with viewing close votes?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, vote-to-close

[This question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3574/logarithmic-advice-language-in-p) had this comment:

> Voted to close as off topic (too basic). – Tsuyoshi Ito 43 mins ago

I therefore assume at least one close vote was cast for this question. As of the moment of writing this, the question is not (yet) closed.

According to [this page](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/privileges/view-close-votes), I should be able to view close votes. They even show a screenshot where this should appear. However, I don't see any such option appearing for me at that question, and I can't remember ever having seen that option appear on any question I've viewed.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Can you not even see a 'close' link ?

Comment: I can see a 'close' link on my own question here, but nothing appears on other people's questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a bug, the privilege you have linked to means that you can see the *close votes for your own questions*.

Part of it reads as

> You may also cast a close or reopen vote on your questions. *With the close/reopen vote privilege, you'll be able **to see** (and cast) close and reopen votes on all questions.*

and that requires +3000 reputation.

Answer (score 5):

In brief, the behavior is correct, and the the description of the privilege itself is not well worded. [This discussion on meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68512/is-the-explanation-of-view-close-votes-misleading) details the issue.

Comment: I'd go beyond 'not well worded' and say that it's 'absolutely correct, and utterly confusing'. If it were me, I'd dedicate an entire sentence to this condition and not just the four-letter word 'your'. Thanks for clearing it up for me though (Kaveh too).